# Spring сохранить файл, чтобы к нему был доступ по ссылке

Tags: java, spring

Как можно сохранить файл из `<input type="file"`, чтобы к нему был доступ по ссылке? Т.е. сохраняя mail.png, его можно было увидеть localhost:8080/images/mail.png.

Сейчас сохраняю так:

```
@PostMapping("/image/save")
    public String imageSave(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                Path path = Paths.get(file.getOriginalFilename());
                Files.write(path, bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианта 2:
1. Сделать ресурс localhost:8080/images/ статическим и тогда все что в нем лежит будет доступно напрямую
2. Сделать контроллер localhost:8080/images, который будет обрабатывать mail.png, получать по имени из любого Вашего места файл и возвращать его.

Comment: Под сделать статическим имеется ввиду: `.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/images/")`?

Comment: Да, именно. Но вроде можно указать и папку за пределами приложения.